# Defining the size of control group in chi square statistics

Tags: chi-squared-test, epidemiology, control-group, prevalence

I'm trying to compare the prevalence rate of autism in offspring of mothers with and without gestational diabetes. I gathered data from 1000 women, 8 children have autism (prevalence rate 8/1000). Unfortunately, due to lack of capability to gather data from healthy women as control group I was forced to use epidemiological information for general population in Poland, which is 5,2-8,6/10000.
I want to perform chi square test but I'm not sure how to calculate the prevalence in a legitimate way. Should I extrapolate my outcome to 80/10000, calculate mean popultion prevalence (7,9/10000), round it up to 8/1000 and then put the values in the contingency table? Or should the control group be as big as my experimental group (1000) and the prevalence should be then rounded up from 0,69/1000 to 1/1000? Or should the control group be as big as 1450 so as not to round up (1000/0,69=1450)?